# how do I use windowing functions in sql to persist a record

Tags: sql, lag, windowing

I have a data set where i'm trying to create a "session id" based on a timestamp where certain event happens (i.e. load) in my case

My data:

```
userid  event  timestamp
xyz     load   '2016-12-01 08:21:13:000'
xyz     view   '2016-12-01 08:21:14:000'
xyz     view   '2016-12-01 08:21:16:000'
xyz     exit   '2016-12-01 08:21:17:000'
xyz     load   '2016-12-02 08:01:13:000'
xyz     view   '2016-12-02 08:01:16:000'
abc     load   '2016-12-01 08:11:13:000'
abc     view   '2016-12-01 08:11:14:000'
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to create a new column called session_start_timestamp where the row is marked against the last "load" for each user.

I know how to do this by creating a subset table (by taking the minimum timestamp and self joining), but is there a lag/lead/max/partition function that can do this instead?

The final output should look like:

```
userid  event  timestamp                  session_start_timestamp
xyz     load   '2016-12-01 08:21:13:000'  '2016-12-01 08:21:13:000'
xyz     view   '2016-12-01 08:21:14:000'  '2016-12-01 08:21:13:000'
xyz     view   '2016-12-01 08:21:16:000'  '2016-12-01 08:21:13:000'
xyz     exit   '2016-12-01 08:21:17:000'  '2016-12-01 08:21:13:000'
xyz     load   '2016-12-02 08:01:13:000'  '2016-12-02 08:01:13:000'
xyz     view   '2016-12-02 08:01:16:000'  '2016-12-02 08:01:13:000'
abc     load   '2016-12-01 08:11:13:000'  '2016-12-01 08:11:13:000'
abc     view   '2016-12-01 08:11:14:000'  '2016-12-01 08:11:13:000'
```

Comment: what is your rdbms?

Comment: i am using db2 .

Comment: i can convert mssql code into db2 can you please give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gap/island problem:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/GVN82157)** (postgresql)

1. You calculate the gap or break points.
2. Then using cumulative `SUM()` calculate the groups
3. Then select the `MIN()` time from each group

--

```
WITH gap as (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN "event" = 'load' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as gap
    FROM Table1
), island as (
    SELECT *, SUM(gap) OVER (PARTITION BY "userid" ORDER BY "timestamp" ) as grp
    FROM gap
)    
SELECT *, MIN("timestamp") OVER (PARTITION BY "userid", "grp") as new_timestamp
FROM island
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

You can merge first two queries:

```
WITH island as (
    SELECT *, SUM (CASE WHEN "event" = 'load' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
              OVER (PARTITION BY "userid" ORDER BY "timestamp" ) as grp
    FROM Table1
)    
SELECT *, MIN("timestamp") OVER (PARTITION BY "userid", "grp") as new_timestamp
FROM island
```